# Shuffle multiline folds

Tags: folding, multiple-lines

Suppose I have a bunch of folds for more than one line each. How to make shuffle them as folds not lines?

In case of lines it can be done by external `shuf` or any other command (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17643450/359866 for example).

So the question is for more general case of multiline folds.

P.S. **Example.**

Unfolded:

```
fold1
  subfold text1
fold2
  subfold text2
fold3
  subfold text3
```

Folded:

```
fold1...
fold2...
fold3...
```

After shuffle for example

```
fold2
  subfold text2
fold1
  subfold text1
fold3
  subfold text3
```

Comment: I think this kind of task would be more fitted for [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) rather than vim: In awk it should be easy to define how your fold works to get each section and then printing them randomly should be doable. With Vim it should be doable too but I think that wouldn't be very elegant to write in Vimscript.

Comment: @statox, in this case I should re-implement folding (for each file-type) in `awk` which isn't what I want. I think that in that sense it much more reliable implementation is vimscript folding implementation.

Comment: Of course it has its drawback, I wasn't arguing that you shouldn't do it in Vim, simply that maybe you had more efficient alternative solutions :)

Answer (score 6):

There is a `:folddoclosed` command which iterates over all closed folds (just like `:g` command for the whole buffer) and executes one or more commands on them. So I would close all folds, convert each fold into one long line by replacing the end-of-line with a unique marker, shuffle the lines around, and replace the markers with line-breaks. Something along

```
zM
:folddoclosed s/\n/<EOL>/
:DoTheShuffle
:%s/<EOL>/\r/g
```

Depending on the original text and the shuffling method some cleanup might be necessary afterwards, e.g., removal of superfluous empty lines.